# populate a property based on the other property's value in C# .Net core method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the following method

```
public IActionResult GetAssets(DateTime? ClosingDT = null, string InvestmentLevel = "child", string planCode = null, string PartyID = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var ContactInvBal = Repo.GetFund(this.UserToken.ContactID, ClosingDT, InvestmentLevel, planCode, PartyID);
                decimal TotalAll = ContactInvBal.InvestmentBalances.Sum(b => b.ClosingBalance.HasValue ? b.ClosingBalance.Value : 0.00M);
                var result = ContactInvBal.InvestmentBalances.Select(b => new ContactAssets()
                {
                    Type = "",
                    AssetClass = b.AssetClass,
                    Balance = b.ClosingBalance,
                    Units = b.ClosingUnit,
                    Price = b.ClosingPrice,
                    PercentOfTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(b.ClosingBalance / TotalAll)
                });
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I need to populate Type property based on the AssetClass value
The Type property is currently an empty string  I need to check asset class value  if (1) asset class is IPM then Type is Model, (2)if RET then PPA, (3)if Loan then RNA, and (4)for  all others value for AssestClass then Type will be FUND.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why does `InvestmentBalance` not contain this information? is it out of your control?

Comment: yes . thats how we are getting data. I wont be able to change it

Comment: you could use a dictionary for the mapping or the [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0) feature if you are using .net-core. I don't entirely understand the C# 4.0 tag. which version of C# are you using?

Comment: sry i removed the 4.0 tag that was by mistake .. we are using C#  .Net Core 3.0

Comment: Is AssetClass a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that comes to my mind is to use ternary operators:

```
Type = 
      b.AssetClass == "IPM" ? "Model" 
    : b.AssetClass == "RET" ? "PPA" 
    : b.AssetClass == "Loan" ? "RNA"
    : "FUND"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of switch statement

```
switch(b.AssetClass)
{
case "IPM" :
  Type = "Model";
  break;
case "RET" :
  Type = "PPA";
  break;
case "Loan" :
  Type = "RNA;
  break;
default :
Type = "Fund"
}
```